# ASP.NET HttpSession.Abandon not closing redis connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, httpsession, azure-redis-cache

I'm using redis as my SessionState provider, but i cant get the infrastructure to close the connection when I `Session.Abandon()`... so if a user is simply logging out so another one can login (very common scenario for me, since they share a terminal), i'm racking up connections...

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the timeout configuration? Default is "0", never expire.

Comment: @Dhanuka777 right now is 30 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually redis session state provider does use a connection multiplexer keeping a very low number (like 2 or 3) of open connection for the application. The racking up was because of a third party dll...